# background of UIView gets scaled incorrectly and is offset

Tags: objective-c, ios

I saw other posts but still can't get my background image to scale correctly.  I use a UIView to set a background image because i need the background image to tile vertically.  I set the frame of the UIView to be the same size as my pixel width and height of the png, but the image gets offset and scaled incorrectly.  Could it be because the image has some transparent pixels?  I tried the following:

```
_view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
_view.opaque = NO;
_view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
//_view.layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityTop;
```

Comment: Can you show screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it easier to just make a subclass of `UIView`.  In the subclass, override `drawRect:` to draw your image using `drawAsPatternInRect:`.  That method will fill the view by tiling the image:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect {
    [self.tileImage drawAsPatternInRect:self.bounds];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are using a Image as a background colour.
it would be much better if you used an imageview, and added that as a subview, like this.

//Edit for vertical tiling

```
 int y = 0;
int imgsize = 100; //in pixels
for (i =0; i<max; i++) { //max is the number of tiles you want
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
img.frame = CGRectMake(0,y+imgsize,100,100);
y+=imgsize; //increase y each time(new starting point)
[_view addSubview:img];
}
```

Might not be the best way to do it, but it will work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question properly. Edited my original answer to give you an tiling effect.

Comment: Using `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image]` will have vastly better performance - this is a very brute force way of tiling images, but it eschews all of the best CoreGraphics routines for drawing images (the `[image resizableImageWithCapInsets:{0,0,0,0} resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile]` can create a tiled image handily)